# Dark Mode preferredColorScheme not updating buttons

Tags: ios, swiftui, color-scheme, darkmode

Does anyone know why this might be?

I am trying to give my users the option to set dark mode as a preference within the app.

I am using AppStorage to save the users choice and using preferredColorScheme on the Root view to update the entire app.

For the most part this is working and used to work fine. But since iOS 16/17 Buttons or NavigationLinks don't update their color. For example. I have a white system background that changes to black as expected but the text of all Buttons doesn't change and looks hidden on the black background. Yet normal text updates fine.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("darkMode") var isDarkMode: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
            
            Button {
                //
            } label: {
                Text("click me")
            }
            
            Toggle("", isOn: $isDarkMode)
        }
        .padding()
        .preferredColorScheme(isDarkMode ? .dark : nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Which `ButtonStyle` needs to be used to reproduce this problem? The default button style of `.automatic` uses blue as foregound color, which works against a black or a white background.

Comment: Hey @BenzyNeez thanks for the response. I'm not using a ButtonStyle but instead using custom views that are using black text as default.

e.g

Button {
                    //
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                        .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .medium))
                        .padding(.horizontal, 18)
                }

Comment: When I try that `Button` in isolation, the foreground color is blue. Please can you update the post to include a fully functional reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

I was asking in the comments, how you are styling the buttons. You gave this `Button` as an example:

```swift
Button {} label: {
    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
        .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .medium))
        .padding(.horizontal, 18)
}
```

When I try this in isolation, the foreground color is blue. So I suspect, you must be applying something like `foregroundStyle(.black)` at a higher level. If this is the case, it is not surprising that the foreground color is always black.

To fix, try applying `.foregroundStyle(.primary)` to the button itself:

```swift
Button {} label: {
    // ...
}
.foregroundStyle(.primary)
```

If that doesn't work, try `.tint` instead:

```swift
Button {} label: {
    // ...
}
.tint(.primary)
```

Comment: So, what I've done is set the AccentColor in the Asset Catalog to have light #ffffff and dark #000000 modes. So actually it's nothing to do with Buttons over the issue being with the Accent Color using black and white

Comment: @Dan OK, so I tried creating an `AccentColor` but using black for `Any` and white for `Dark` (because doing it the other way around would mean they would be the same as the system background). The button I was trying in isolation now adopts these colors, without requiring any `.foregroundStyle` or `.tint`. So still not able to reproduce the problem. A more detailed code example and steps to reproduce would be very helpful.

Comment: I've updated my original post with some example code. It's having the same issue. And using The black/white accent color

Comment: The issue seems to be with the Toggle. It is changing the colour but the wrong way around putting black on black and white on white

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems when only setting light/dark mode on the Accent Color in the Asset catalog, and then changing the preferred color scheme in the app, the accent color is doing the opposite to what I'd expect. Showing black when it should be showing white and vice versa. I don't know why this is.

The solution I've found is to set .foregroundStyle(.accent) on each view that uses the accent colour.

If anyone has a better solution please let me know.